# Text extraction from PDF using PDFBox 2.0

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm trying to use PDFBox 2.0 for text extraction. I would like to get information on the font size of specific characters and the position rectangle of that character on the page.
I've implemented this in PDFBox 1.6 using a PDFTextStripper:

```java
    PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(is);
    try{
        parser.parse();
    }catch(IOException e){

    }
    COSDocument cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
    PDDocument pdd = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
    final StringBuffer extractedText = new StringBuffer();
    PDFTextStripper textStripper = new PDFTextStripper(){
        @Override
        protected void processTextPosition(TextPosition text) {
            extractedText.append(text.getCharacter());
            logger.debug("text position: "+text.toString());
        }
    };
    textStripper.setSuppressDuplicateOverlappingText(false);
    for(int pageNum = 0;pageNum<pdd.getNumberOfPages();pageNum++){
        PDPage page = (PDPage) pdd.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(pageNum);
        textStripper.processStream(page, page.findResources(), page.getContents().getStream());
    }
    pdd.close();
```

But in the 2.0 version of PDFBox, the `processStream` method has been removed.
How can I achieve the same with PDFBox 2.0?

I've tried the following:

```java
        PDDocument pdd = PDDocument.load(inputStream);
        PDFTextStripper textStripper = new PDFTextStripper(){
            @Override
            protected void processTextPosition(TextPosition text){
                int pos = PDFdocument.length();
                String textadded = text.getUnicode();
                Range range = new Range(pos,pos+textadded.length());
                int pagenr = this.getCurrentPageNo();
                Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D.Float(text.getX(),text.getY(),text.getWidth(),text.getHeight());
            }
        };
        textStripper.setSuppressDuplicateOverlappingText(false);
        for(int pageNum = 0;pageNum<pdd.getNumberOfPages();pageNum++){
            PDPage page = (PDPage) pdd.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(pageNum);
            textStripper.processPage(page);
        }
        pdd.close();
```

The `processTextPosition(TextPosition text)` method does not get called.
Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Comment: Please look at the DrawPrintTextLocations example in the source code, this does what you are apparently intending to do. It uses the writeString() call.

Comment: Thanks, that example does exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`DrawPrintTextLocations` example](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/DrawPrintTextLocations.java?view=markup), suggested by @tilmanhausherr, provided the solution to my problem.

The parser is started using the following code (the `inputStream` is the input stream from the URL of the PDF file):

```
    PDDocument pdd = null;
    try {
        pdd = PDDocument.load(inputStream);
        PDFParserTextStripper stripper = new PDFParserTextStripper(PDFdocument,pdd);
        stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
        for (int i=0;i<pdd.getNumberOfPages();i++){
            stripper.stripPage(i);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // throw error
    } finally {
        if (pdd!=null) {
            try {
                pdd.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
        }
    }
```

This code uses a custom subclass of `PDFTextStripper`:

```
class PDFParserTextStripper extends PDFTextStripper {

    public PDFParserTextStripper() throws IOException {
        super();
    }


    public void stripPage(int pageNr) throws IOException {
        this.setStartPage(pageNr+1);
        this.setEndPage(pageNr+1);
        Writer dummy = new OutputStreamWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
        writeText(document,dummy); // This call starts the parsing process and calls writeString repeatedly.
    }



    @Override
    protected void writeString(String string,List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException {
        for (TextPosition text : textPositions) {
            System.out.println("String[" + text.getXDirAdj()+","+text.getYDirAdj()+" fs="+text.getFontSizeInPt()+" xscale="+text.getXScale()+" height="+text.getHeightDir()+" space="+text.getWidthOfSpace()+" width="+text.getWidthDirAdj()+" ] "+text.getUnicode());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This worked fine, thank you. Why the PDFRenderer & PDPage objects though?

Comment: @Darajan You are right. They are probably a remnant of earlier attempts. I will remove them from the answer.

Comment: @Dieudonné Can you please guide me.. Where is the "PDFdocument" class?

Comment: @HamzaHafeez That is just a custom class, it is not part of PDFBox.

Comment: ok
can you see my query? i am facing the problem. If you know how to solve the issue please guide me.
[Please Click Here To see My Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39952344/how-to-re-populate-the-pagerview-view-using-pageradapter)

Comment: Thank you, that helped.  Note atm there is a typo:  Line 4 should read PDFParserTextStripper stripper = new PDFParserTextStripper(pdd);
and in the subclass line 3: public PDFParserTextStripper(PDDocument pdd) throws IOException {
as well as document = pdd;  as user 4332758 did.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation which uses @tilmanhausherr suggestion(s):

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.TextPosition;

class PDFParserTextStripper extends PDFTextStripper 
{
    public PDFParserTextStripper(PDDocument pdd) throws IOException 
    {  
        super();
        document = pdd;
    }

    public void stripPage(int pageNr) throws IOException 
    {
        this.setStartPage(pageNr+1);
        this.setEndPage(pageNr+1);
        Writer dummy = new OutputStreamWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
        writeText(document,dummy); // This call starts the parsing process and calls writeString repeatedly.
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeString(String string,List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException 
    {
        for (TextPosition text : textPositions) {
            System.out.println("String[" + text.getXDirAdj()+","+text.getYDirAdj()+" fs="+text.getFontSizeInPt()+" xscale="+text.getXScale()+" height="+text.getHeightDir()+" space="+text.getWidthOfSpace()+" width="+text.getWidthDirAdj()+" ] "+text.getUnicode());
        }
    }

    public static void extractText(InputStream inputStream)
    {
        PDDocument pdd = null;

        try 
        {
            pdd = PDDocument.load(inputStream);
            PDFParserTextStripper stripper = new PDFParserTextStripper(pdd);
            stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
            for (int i=0; i<pdd.getNumberOfPages(); i++)
            {
                stripper.stripPage(i);
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // throw error
        } 
        finally 
        {
            if (pdd != null) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    pdd.close();
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        File f = new File("C:\\PathToYourPDF\\pdfFile.pdf");
        FileInputStream fis = null;

        try 
        {
            fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            extractText(fis);
        } 
        catch(IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally 
        {
            try 
            {
                if(fis != null)
                    fis.close();
            } 
            catch(IOException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```